# WPF Images same width/height/dpi but different dispay

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-controls

I cut two images from one larger image. The both cut images are 300x148 and have got 96 dpi.

I display them this way:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image1, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
<Image Source="{Binding Image2, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```

Problem is that I visually see the difference in the height. More curious thing is, that when I swap them:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image2, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
<Image Source="{Binding Image1, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```

The **height difference changes** but still exists.

I put some logging into `ImageCoverter` to log the returned value and the width/height/dpi values do not differ.

I don't have any styles which affect images.

Are there any other fields which I should also consider?

**EDIT**
That is how I create the 300x148 image. I pass the cropped image and the width:

```
public static Bitmap Scale(Bitmap image, double width)
{
    double ratio = width / image.Width;
    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var scaledImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(scaledImage))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: Try to set `Stretch="None"` and also show us the code where you create the cropped images.

Comment: I tried to use it, nothing happens

Comment: @N.Zukowski, try use Image1 as source for both and observe what happens

Comment: @ASh I made it already and two same images do not differ in the height. So I think the both different images somehow do have different heights but how can it happen?

Comment: You just want to scale the entire image to a different pixel width and height, instead of cutting a crop out of a larger image, right?

Comment: I have got a large 6MP image. I am interested in two areas of this image, this areas are 2450x1210 large. I need that large images, because I have to do some OCR. After I did OCR I can scale this areas (2450x1210) to be 300x148 to display them in the GUI

Comment: Then use [CroppedBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) for cropping, and simply set `<Image Width="300" Height="148" .../>`. There's no need to use any WinForms Graphics or Bitmap stuff.

Comment: What are your images contained in? (ie stackpanel, grid etc).  Also, can you show a screenshot of the size difference?

Answer (score -1):

Image is a control that displays a picture.
Can't you just set the height and width of your Image controls?

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100"
```

Comment: Don't write this as a question. Instead, show how the XAML would look like.